# How to show the values of an object without the name of foreign key class in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django

The `Customer` class has a foreign key to `User` class. I want to return this information but I don't want to show user__  before username, first_name, etc.

```
data = {"customers": list(p.values("id", "user__username", "user__first_name",
                                       "user__last_name", "user__email", "phone",
                                       "address", "balance"))}
```

How can I get something like that:

```
{
"customers": [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "username": "leon2",
        "first_name": "lee",
        "last_name": "michalson",
        "email": "hamed@example.com",
        "phone": "042-22334455",
        "address": "Tehran, No.1",
        "balance": 20000
    }

]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate):

```
from django.db.models import F


for field in ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'):
    p = p.annotate(**{field: F('user__' + field)})

data = {"customers": list(p.values("id", "username", "first_name",
                                       "last_name", "email", "phone",
                                       "address", "balance"))}
```